# Ordenar una operacion aritmetica, que se reciba de manera horizontal y la retorne de manera vertical usando python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando crear una funcion que pueda recibir operaciones aritneticas de manera horizontal y las ordene de manera vertical, por ejemplo:

13+26 y que la funcion las ordene de manera

**13  +

26

-------**

lo que he intentado hasta ahora

```py
import re
pregunta = input("ingresa las operaciones aritmeticas: ")
def arithmetic_arranger(problems):
    patron = r'(\w)([0-9])'
 
    return re.sub(patron,r'\1\2 \n------', problems)
problema = pregunta
resultado =arithmetic_arranger(problema)
print(resultado)
```

pero no me funciona, me ordena la operación pero de manera desordenada, quisiera hacer saber o recordarme si se puede hacer sin usar 'regular expresiones'

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algo interesante, lo que se me ha ocurrido ha sido separar los número de los caracteres, luego ir mostrándolos por pantalla y poniendo el signo al final, habrá uno que otro problema pero lo solucionaremos.

Primero creamos nuestra expresión regular para hacer que coincida con los símbolos de las operaciones básicas y separamos la cadena con ayuda del método `split` del módulo `re`, también le quitamos los espacios (al inicio y final) con el método `strip()` (es un método de los strings)

```
import re

def ordenar_operacion(operacion):
    regex = re.compile(r"(\+|\-|\*|\/)")
    opc = [op.strip() for op in regex.split(operacion) if op !=""]
    longitud = 6 #esto nos servirá para que quede "indentado"
```

Con esto ya tenemos lo básico, ahora necesitamos imprimir la operación por pantalla, para esto ocuparemos un ciclo `while`, con el que recorreremos la lista `opc`, en caso el elemento sea un número imprimiremos el número seguido del elemento siguiente, que como sabemos, será un signo, luego sumamos 2 a nuestra variable de control (`i`), en caso el primer elemento sea un signo (la operación puede ser `-13+6`) entonces imprimiremos el signo seguido del numero y al final el signo siguiente (que indica la operación a realizar). Para hacer esto se me ocurrió hacer con un `flag` que indique si el elemento es un signo (del número) y si es así imprimiremos ese y luego sumamos 1 y usamos `continue` para que el programa siga y entonces a la siguiente iteración el elemento será un numero y ya no tendremos problemas, veamos el código para entenderlo mejor

```py
    #dentro de la función
    #...

    #inicializamos las variables
    flag = None
    i = 0
    #hacemos el ciclo
    while i in range(len(opc)):
        try:
            int(opc[i]) #verificamso que sea entero
            # imprimimos el numero y al final el signo
            print(f"{opc[i]}{(longitud-len(opc[i]))*' '}", end=f"{opc[i+1]}\n")
        except:
            if regex.match(opc[i]): #si es un signo
                print(opc[i], end="")#imprimimos el signo
                i+=1 #sumamos 1
                continue #regresamos al inicio
            # imprimimos el numero y al final el signo (solo en caso lo tenga)
            print(f"{opc[i]}{(longitud-len(opc[i]))*' '}", end=f"{'' if i==len(opc)-1 else opc[i+1]}")
        i+=2
```

Con `opc[i]` simplemente obtenemos el elemento actual. Con `(longitud-len(opc[i]))*' '` imprimimos espacios en blanco para que todo quede *indentado*, para eso restamos la longitud (que es el número que caracteres que se mostrará) con la longitud del número, con eso hallamos los espacios restantes para poder colocar el signo y que así quede en orden. El parámetro `end` indica que es lo que se mostrará al final, en este caso indicamos que se muestre el signo, que vendría a ser el elemento siguiente `f"{opc[i+1]}\n"` (`\n` es un salto de línea)

Lo mismo es para el caso del bloque `except` (se cumple cuando hay un signo) solo que en el parámetro `end` se utiliza un operador ternario, esto es para que cuando estemos en el ultimo elemento de la lista ya no imprima nada y en caso de haber más, si imprima.

**Probamos**

```py
ordenar_operacion("13+26")
print('\n')
ordenar_operacion("-13 + 900/3")
```

**Resultado**

```
13    +
26    

-13    +
900   /
3
```

Aquí solo he *indentado* los signos, más no los números, puedes aplicar el mismo concepto que utilice para hacerlo.

Si quieres agregar el resultado lo único que tendrías que hacer es agregar una linea
horizontal `print("-"*longitud)` y debajo poner el resultado de la operación, que bien podrías obtenerla usando `eval(operación)`

Comment: Interesante approach, vere si me funciona al igual que la otra respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que las expresiones consisten de enteros, con o sin espacios intercalados, como

```
expresion = "12 + 34/45*6-12002"
```

la expresión regular `(\d+\D)` reconoce y captura un entero seguido de un no-digito, que por las condiciones del problema, tiene que ser una operación aritmética.

Los espacios intercalados molestan; los eliminare con un `replace(" ", "")`. Luego de eso, agregare un espacio en blanco al final, para que la expresión regular reconozca el último entero.

```
import re

patron=re.compile(r"(\d+\D)")
expresion = "12 + 34/45*6-12002"

lista = patron.findall(expresion.replace(" ", "") + " ")
ancho = max(len(parte) for parte in lista)
for parte in lista:
    print(f"{elemento[:-1]:>{ancho}} {elemento[-1]}")
print('-' * ancho)
```

`findall()` encuentra todas las ocurrencias del patrón indicado, produciendo

```
['12+', '34/', '45*', '6-', '12002 ']
```

Necesito calcular el máximo ancho de los elementos, para poder imprimir alineado:

```
ancho = max(len(parte) for parte in lista)
```

y sólo me queda recorrer la lista imprimiendo.

#### Demo

```
import re

patron=re.compile(r"(\d+\D)")
expresion = "12 + 34/45*6-12002"

lista = patron.findall(expresion.replace(" ", "") + " ")
print(lista)
ancho = max(len(parte) for parte in lista)
for parte in lista:
    print(f"{parte[:-1]:>{ancho}} {parte[-1]}")
print('-' * ancho)
```

produce:

```
    12 +
    34 /
    45 *
     6 -
 12002  
------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, intentare hacerlo

Comment: Gracias nuevamente por la solucion, ahora me encuentro con el problema de que se agregan varias expresiones en la misma string es decir, que debo convertir varias operaciones aritmeticas  separadas por comillas, intente realizar varas variables pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo 

"32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"

Comment: Usa `split(',')` para separar la entrada en una lista de strings `["232 + 698", "3801 - 2", ....]`. Luego recorre la lista `for exp in lista:` y aplica el método a cada expresión